# Multiple itemscope location schemes

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I use itemscopes for a gallery, based in Brazil but they also have two other locations for the exhibitions somewhere else, all of them showing up in the footer.

Can I use multiple Location Schemes on a page? If so, how would I do this? Is it fine if I just duplicate the following, or should I split it up with the first belonging to Organization and the other two to Places?

```html
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <span itemprop="name" style="display:none;">Gallery</span>
    <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">{!! $street !!}</span><br>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">{!! $town !!}</span><br>
    <span itemprop="postalCode">{!! $postal !!}</span>
    <span itemprop="addressRegion">{!! \App\Info::val('adresscountry') !!}</span><br>
    <span itemprop="telephone">{!! $phone !!}</span><br><br>
    <span>{!! $openinghours !!}</span><br><br>
    <span itemprop="email">mail@gallery.com</span><br><br>
    </span>
</p>
```

It is one organization that owns three places where exhibitions are held. It would be nice if every place would be featured on search machines, no need for the specific exhibitions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following doesn’t necessarily lead to rich results in search engines. In case of Google Search, it seems they don’t offer a rich result for places (and even if they would, it would probably require a dedicated page per place). However, they have a [rich result for events](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events).

You could provide an [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) item with three [`location`](http://schema.org/location) values:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" id="loc-1"><!-- location 1 --></div>
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" id="loc-2"><!-- location 2 --></div>
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" id="loc-3"><!-- location 3 --></div>
</div>
```

For each [`ExhibitionEvent`](http://schema.org/ExhibitionEvent), you could reference its location (assuming that the places are part of the footer on the event pages, too) via the `itemref` attribute:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExhibitionEvent" itemref="loc-2">
</div>
```